# Use SSL in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I want to go from HTTP to HTTPS on my wordpress site. So far, I have done the following:

1. Changed the siteurl and home addresses to https://www.example.com
2. In wp-config.php file added

   ```
   define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
   define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true); // I read this was deprecated, but I was desperate
   /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
   ```
3. In .htaccess I have:

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

So now I face two problems:
1. css styles do not load
2. I cannot access wp-admin panel and I have error 401 The page isn’t redirecting properly

I`ve tried a lot of things and finally I really need your help, thanks!!!

EDIT!!!!
I removed the lines 
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);

and now it finds its way to the admin panel, but still the style files are not loaded.

Comment: Check your error console and make sure everything is loading correctly. You may also need to update your site url in the database or follow the directions here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/changing-your-wordpress-domain-name-6495 . It's probably referencing HTTP instead of HTTPS, which most browsers will balk at.

Comment: you use apache, nginx or other ?

Comment: yes, I edited the site url in the database. It is Apache. In the log I don't see anything specific. However in the console I have a list with errors which look like this: Blocked loading mixed active content “http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.1”

Comment: Is it possible that you (or the theme writer) hard-coded the css style link url to point to the http url?  You can inspect the page to find out, or you can check the error console (it should show up there as not being loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Wordpress Plugin, it will save you time.

I use personally this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/